# Tikz, text along path, accents

Tags: tikz-pgf

In a M(not-)WE as below, is there a way to insert  `\'{e}`, `\'{a}` and similar commands? The simple minded solution, just insert them, does not seem to work.

EDIT: If I compile it, I get a `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate.`. If I try to `> r`, compilation halts anyway.
If I embrace accents commands in their own pair of braces, I get the same error, but `>r` takes up compilation to the output. If I use the key `raise` too, it runs fine.

```
\documentclass {beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, decorations.markings, decorations.text, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0 :4cm) node (x) {AAAAAA} 
    (180:4cm) node (y) {BBBBB};
    \def\myshift#1{\raisebox{1ex}}
    \draw [-{Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]}, thick, postaction={decorate, decoration={text along path, text align=center, text={|\sffamily\myshift| \`{e}, \`{a}, \`{u}, \`{i}, \`{o} }}}] (y) to [bend left=45]  (x);
    \def\myshift#1{\raisebox{-2.5ex}}
    \draw [-{Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]}, thick, postaction={decorate, decoration={text along path, reverse path, text align=center, text={|\sffamily\myshift|Ok \textbf{Pk}, \textcolor{red}{Ok}  } }}] (x) to [bend left=45] (y);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are missing a closing `}` after `\`{o}}}` which is causing your error. However, another error generates after adding the `}`, namely: `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate.
`, could you confirm adding the closing `}` solves that issue on your system and then edit your question to ask why the new error is occurring please?

Comment: You define `\myshift` to have one argument but it's actually missing in the replacement text. Sometimes, this is what we want but I don't think it is here. Take a look [at the manual](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#pgf.decorations.text) in how to use this decoration. `\textcolor` and `\textbf` aren't really working here that way. All the accented letters need to be in their own pair of braces

Comment: missing `}` is a cut&paste misprint, sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. you're missing a closing brace after text={...` for the top arrow;
2. problematic combinations should be braced;
3. you define `\myshift` to take an argument, but you shouldn't.

Besides, using `\myshift` is not the best approach anyway, as Ti*k*Z has the key `raise` for the same purpose.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, decorations.markings, decorations.text, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0:4cm) node (x) {AAAAAA} (180:4cm) node (y) {BBBBB};
  \draw[
    -{Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]},
    thick,
    postaction={
      decorate,
      decoration={
        text along path,
        raise=1ex,
        text align=center,
        text={|\sffamily|{\`{e}}, {\`{a}}, {\`{u}}, {\`{i}}, {\`{o}}},
      }
    }
  ] (y) to [bend left=45]  (x);
  \draw[
    -{Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]},
    thick,
    postaction={
      decorate,
      decoration={
        text along path,
        reverse path,
        raise=-2.5ex,
        text align=center,
        text={|\sffamily|Ok {\textbf{Pk}}, {\textcolor{red}{Ok}}}
      }
    }
  ] (x) to [bend left=45] (y);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. How is that we need to embrace by a pair of braces `{}`?

Comment: @mario The text to be placed along the curve is scanned item by item, so `\'{a}` would be two items, namely `\'` and `a`. Similarly for parts embedded in `\textcolor`.